# Is it OK $E(XY|Y)\overset?=YE(X|Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> When it is allowed to pull a r.v. out of the expectation, i.e.

$E(XY|Y)\overset?=YE(X|Y)\tag1$.

or even

$E(Y^2|Y)\overset?=Y^2\tag2$

in the computation rules it is written that if,

$XY\ge0$ or both r.v. are in $L^1(\star)$

it is allowed. But what if other conditions were given instead of $(\star)$, for example

$E(X^2|Y)=Y^2$ and $E(X|Y)=Y$

Is then $(1)\ \&\ (2)$ still valid ?

Comment: As long as all the conditional expectation involved in are well-defined, the identity should continue to hold. Non-negativity and integrability are two such condition that makes conditional expectation well-defined.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee I think you're misunderstanding my question, see edit

Comment: What I am telling is that $\text{(1)}$ holds as soon as both $\mathbb{E}[XY\mid Y]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ are *defined* at all, and likewise for $\text{(2)}$. You do not need to pour in extra conditions so long as all the involved quantities make sense. So the question shifts to whether your conditions (or the implicit assumptions that make your conditions well-defined) render them defined, and this boils down to asking whether they imply the involved random variables are either non-negative or integrable.

Comment: Of course, I heard that there are some generalized notion of conditional expectation so that it makes sense to a broader class of random variables. But such notions have not been incorporated into the major part of probability theory, and I am skeptical that they are employed in your context.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]=X$$
when $X$ is $\mathcal G-$measurable. So obviously, for any Borel function, $$\mathbb E[f(Y)\mid Y]=f(Y).$$

Comment: My only complaint is that $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]$ need not be defined for any random variable $X$ under the standard definition of conditional expectation, which requires either integrability or non-negativity of $X$. Are you using some generalized notions here?

Answer (score 0):

Let us make it precise. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability
space. Let $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ be a sub $\sigma$-algebra.
Let $X,Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be random variables such that
$Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. We have that $E\left[XY\mid\mathcal{G}\right]=YE\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]$,
provided that $XY$ and $X$ are integrable. Note that we do not require
that $Y$ is integrable.

Firstly, requiring that $XY$ and $Y$ are integrable makes sense
because conditional expectation is only defined for integrable random
variables (at least, this is true for almost all textbooks). Firstly,
we prove that the proposition is true if $Y$ is a bounded. (I skip
the proof).

Let $A_{n}=[|Y|\leq n]$. Note that $1_{A_{n}}\rightarrow1$ pointwisely.
Now, $E\left[XY1_{A_{n}}\mid\mathcal{G}\right]=E\left[X(Y1_{A_{n}})\mid\mathcal{G}\right]=(Y1_{A_{n}})E\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]$
because $Y1_{A_{n}}$is bounded and $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Observe
that $|XY1_{A_{n}}|\leq|XY|$, $XY$ is integrable, and $XY1_{A_{n}}\rightarrow XY$.
By the conditional version of dominated convergence theorem, we have
$E[XY1_{A_{n}}\mid\mathcal{G}]\rightarrow E[XY\mid\mathcal{G}]$ (a.e.).
Therefore, letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ on both sides, we are done.

Comment: '' Suppose that all the random variables under consideration are integrable.'' that is exactly what I want to replace with new conditions

Comment: @counterfeit why? If the RVs aren’t integrable how do you expect to define expectations let alone conditional expectations?

Comment: Therefore, at least, we require that $XY$ and $X$ are integrable.